# how to access multidimensional array value in react?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, syntax, case

What I'm trying to do is to get value from 'coords' array and output it to webpage. Other components are rendering fine. Right now I'm getting an error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Do I have some problems with syntax or I simply cant reach `coords` array?

Here is the full code of component

```
class Ships extends Component{
//get random integer from min to max value
getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
  }


LShip(){

var startXCoord =  this.getRandomInt(0,9);
var startYCoord =  this.getRandomInt(0,9);
var coords = [];
//orientation will be chosen randomly
var orientation = this.getRandomInt(1,4);
switch (orientation) {
  case 1:
    return(
 this.setState.coords =[
          {'xcoord':this.startXCoord,'ycoord':this.startYCoord},
          {'xcoord':this.startXCoord+1,'ycoord':this.startYCoord},
          {'xcoord':this.startXCoord + 2,'ycoord':this.startYCoord},
          {'xcoord':this.startXCoord,'ycoord':this.startYCoord+1}
        ]
    )
    break;

  case 2:
  return(
  this.setState.coords = [
          {'xcoord':this.startXCoord,'ycoord':this.startYCoord},
         {'xcoord':this.startXCoord+1,'ycoord':this.startYCoord},
         {'xcoord':this.startXCoord + 2,'ycoord':this.startYCoord},
         {'xcoord':this.startXCoord+1,'ycoord':this.startYCoord}
        ]
        )
    break;

  case 3:
  return (
  this.setState.coords =[
           {'xcoord':this.startXCoord,'ycoord':this.startYCoord},
         {'xcoord':this.startXCoord,'ycoord':this.startYCoord+1},
         {'xcoord':this.startXCoord,'ycoord':this.startYCoord + 2},
         {'xcoord':this.startXCoord+1,'ycoord':this.startYCoord}
       ]
     )
    break;

  case 4:
  return(
  this.setState.coords =[
           {'xcoord':this.startXCoord,'ycoord':this.startYCoord},
           {'xcoord':this.startXCoord,'ycoord':this.startYCoord+1},
           {'xcoord':this.startXCoord,'ycoord':this.startYCoord + 2},
           {'xcoord':this.startXCoord,'ycoord':this.startYCoord+1},
         ]
       )
    break;

  default:console.log('something went wrong');
      break;
}
}



IShip(IshipCount){
  this.length = 3;
  var startXCoord =  this.getRandomInt(1,10);
  var startYCoord =  this.getRandomInt(1,10);
  var coords = new Array[startXCoord,startYCoord];
}
DotShip(DotShipCount){
  this.length = 1;
  var xCoord =  this.getRandomInt(1,10);
  var startYCoord =  this.getRandomInt(1,10);
  var coords = new Array[xCoord,startYCoord];
}







render(){
  return(
    <h1>{this.coords[0].xcoord}</h1>
  )
}
}
```

Comment: When your render method runs `this.coords` is probably not defined yet. You can do a check to make sure it's defined first. Something like `{this.cords && this.coords[0].xcoord}`

Comment: I'm getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined . So how should I fix it? make it some sort async?

Comment: Where are you calling the LShip() function? Can you update your question with the entire component code. Or at least showing how you're calling LShip()?

Comment: just added full component code

Comment: It actually looks like there's multiple issues. I'd start with making sure you're function actually works and then update your question. After that, you should read about component lifecycle methods and component state in the react docs. Your function is never actually called in your component. After you fix your function use `componentDidMount` to call your function.

Comment: thanks a lot, I will do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your this reference is probably different in the place that you are setting and calling it.

Either bind the function to this in the constructor like

```
this.LShip = this.LShip.bind(this);
```

Or maybe better yet store your coords in your state `this.state` and access it via `this.state.coords[0].xcoord`. This has the added benefit that your component will re-render if these change.